# How to compare Observed vs Predicted Outcomes for a Binary Dependent Variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, spss, biostatistics

I have created a binary Logistic Regression model to predict if patients in a particular state, will die based on 10 or so predictors (demographics, income, physiological values, etc.) My dependent variable (death) is binary and I converted my predicted probabilities from continuous to binary by assigning cutt-off values for alive/dead (group associations). The goal is to see if the amount of observed deaths, within a given year, is close to the predicted amount.

So far I have validated the performance of the model using other methods (analyzing calibration and discrimination) and am now using it to see if the state had more or less observed deaths than the predicted amount.

So for 1999, the model predicted 35 patients to die when in reality, 54 patients had actually died. **How do I determine if the 54 patient deaths is, or is not, significantly different from the predicted 35 patients?**

Side Note: I am just an undergraduate student without advanced training in statistics/SPSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you apply your model to each patient separately? or do you run a regression on the aggregate number of deaths?

Comment: individually, I then summate the predicted  outcomes for each year. Each patient gets a 'mortality score' from 0-1. I then assigned a cutoff value: anyone with a score >0.33 is reclassified as 1.0 (dead). All the 1's are tallied. Now Im basically trying to see if the people actually dead is significantly different from the people predicted to be dead by my model.

Comment: Don't assign a cutoff value; just add up the probabilities and use that as a basis for comparison.  This works because the probability that a patient dies is equal to the expected number of deaths the patient experiences (between 0 and 1); adding up all the individual expected number of deaths will give you the total expected number of deaths.

Comment: okay, but what test do I use for the comparison of the two groups (predicted vs actual)??